# How to start script in HTML without <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, wavemaker

[image]I'm using a low-code development platform called WaveMaker right now, and it gives you the option to customize the "markup" of the page (HTML, but you can't really edit `<head>`; the whole thing is kind of weird), the Javascript of the page, particularly with events like onpageload, etc., the style of the page (CSS), and the page's variables (JSON). I'm trying to embed Formstack forms, but every time the Markup section encounters a `<script>` tag, it deletes everything after the end of the tag. [This is what the markup page looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htSgw.png) I contacted support and they seemed to indicate that this was on purpose. Is there any way to make HTML run script included in-line without saying `<script>`? PS: I would be able to embed using iFrames, but for some reason the iFrames aren't working on the iPhone test program, even though they're working on the simulator.

Comment: Are you using a webview? I had trouble with iframes too, there's html you should be including that makes it work. www.iframe.ly helps us out with that. (i dont have any affiliation).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it's a webview or not. Were you using WaveMaker? When I tried to use iFrame, I was using basically an HTML snippet widget they included (that doesn't really allow '<script>' either from what I can tell)

Comment: In your image of the markup page, why not just click "script" at the top and put your scripts there? I've never used WaveMaker and you never told us what you're end goal is but that seems like the first place I'd look.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I tried to do that, but the issue is that the entire HTML that I'm trying to embed combines <script> and <noscript> and a bunch of other stuff in a row. So I'm having trouble embedding the "script" tab section in the "Markup" section. I've tried, but not with much success

Comment: use an event attrib to inject an external script into the document; a small amount of code to open up an unlimited amount.

Comment: @dandavis so you mean running a local .js document in an event?

Comment: i was thinkning more a url, a `<script src=>`

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is put it inside an HTML event attribute.

```
<body onload="/*your JS here*/">

</body>
```

If that does not work, try attaching onload to another HTML element or try one of the other event handlers (though I believe that they should have taken this into account as well)

Comment: I can't usually get away with using <body> either. So would you recommend sticking it on '<wm-page-content>' (see the image I linked to in the OP) instead?

Comment: I suggest trying to add those to any html element, just try around (but if it doesn't work for one of those, I guess they blocked it and it won't work for all the others as well)

Comment: thank you! I tried that, but it didn't quite work as expected. I just took the <script> section of the code I'm trying to use, but it produced an unexpected error (see the newer screenshot I uploaded to my OP).

Comment: No, you need to put actual javascript code in there and not a src link

Comment: When I try that, for some reason it doesn't work. I think the issue is that the javascript that the URL goes to is a ton of paragraphs, so I think it doesn't realize that it's still supposed to be script and not HTML

Comment: Does it work if you are trying a simple `alert("something");` ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
<body onload="javascript:(function(){
// you can place your code here it should run
alert('ok')
})()">

</body>
```

Comment: It's really weird, I tried that, and it didn't seem to work either. Thank you though!! PS: for more details on what happened, see the answer above this one. I encountered basically the same issues.

Comment: I found this may be it will be helpful 
http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.5/JavaScript#HExecutingJavaScriptonPageLoading

Answer (score 1):

In [Avatao](https://avatao.com)'s Senior Web Security Career Path, there is a hacking task, where you need to insert malicious javascript code - but the <script> is tag filtered (other tags aren't). [Aenadon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574894/how-to-start-script-in-html-without-script-tag/44574998#44574998) gived me one solution:

```
<body onload="your JS here"> </body>
```

After submitting that, I checked the official solution, and I found that:

```
<img src="x" onerror=alert('xss')>
```